# AzureSynapse ForEach SQL INSERT giving ??? for foreign text

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, azure-synapse

I am a Data Scientist who has been given a Data Engineering task and I am seriously struglling. Please help! I am very new to AzureSynapse and am facing an issue with inserts into my MSSQL DB.

I have a Lookup activity which reads a .json file, followed by a ForEach command which adds some columns and then inserts the rows into my DB.

The issue I am facing is that the foreign text is showing on the DB as ?????. The columns are set as dtype NVARCHAR, which can accept foreign text strings and the output of both the Lookup and ForEach activities have the correct format.

Why is the text showing as ??? on the DB and how can I fix this issue? Maybe my insert statement is incorrect?

I have posted screenshots below. Many thanks for any support.

Pipeline:
[image: Pipeline]

Lookup Output:
[image: Lookup Output]

ForEach Output:
[image: ForEach Output]

ForEach Activity:
[image: ForEach Activity]

ForEach Script:
[image: ForEach Script]

DB dtypes:
[image]

DB Results:
[image: DB Results]

Comment: I didn't publish and lost connection. Remade the identical pipeline with clearer names. The screenshots make it appear that the script and foreach activities have the same name, but they do not in the pipeline. Still getting the identical output

Comment: The backing columns may be `nvarchar` but the screenshots show that you're still using `varchar` type string literals. Have you tried using National Character literals which have the `N` prefix? e.g.: compare the outputs from `select N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ', 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'`

Comment: This was indeed the solution. Tried this last night and it worked. Thank you for the reply AlwaysLearning!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was hilariously simple. All I had to do was preprend an N before the Values where they were intended to be nvarchar. i.e. instead of '@{item().Jobtitle}' it should be N'@{item().Jobtitle}'.

Prepended the N to all NVARCHAR values and it shows in the DB with the foreign text.